# How to check if a process is running in windows using python 2.2?

Tags: python, python-2.2

I need to verify is a process is running in windows (all versions upper windows xp) using only python 2.2. Any idea?

Comment: Why the hack is somebody using Python 2.2 in 2016?!

Comment: legacy system, unfortunately it is too large to be migrated at that time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:

```
from win32com.client import GetObject
WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')

if len(WMI.ExecQuery('select * from Win32_Process where Name like "%s%s"' % ("process_name",'%'))) > 0:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works in python 2.7 on Windows. (I'm not sure it works in 2.2...)

I used check_output() function to hook the output of the 'tasklist', the Windows command which shows the current running processes. You can parse the result of get_tasklist() to get the pid, process name, etc.

```
import subprocess

def get_tasklist():
    return subprocess.check_output('tasklist')

print get_tasklist()
```

[image: example]

How about upgrading your python to 2.7, unless you have a special reason to use 2.2??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/305279/

Regards